# Difference between anova and Anova function

Tags: r, anova

What is the difference between `Anova(data)`and `anova(data)`?

```
> anova(res.full)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Sales
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq   F value    Pr(>F)    
Promotional.Accounts  1   1070    1070   35.0800 0.0001465 ***
Active.Accounts       1  44337   44337 1453.2067 3.680e-12 ***
Competing.Brands      1  43331   43331 1420.2314 4.124e-12 ***
Potential             1     16      16    0.5146 0.4895772    
Residuals            10    305      31                        
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> Anova(res.full)
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: Sales
                     Sum Sq Df   F value    Pr(>F)    
Promotional.Accounts    275  1    9.0193   0.01327 *  
Active.Accounts       27371  1  897.1238 4.025e-11 ***
Competing.Brands      42877  1 1405.3398 4.346e-12 ***
Potential                16  1    0.5146   0.48958    
Residuals               305 10                        
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’
```

I don't understand why in each table the F statistic for each factor is different.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that includes example data and complete code that includes the package(s) you're using (in this case, where the `Anova` function is coming from).

Comment: There is something conceptual that I don't understand, no need to add data because I don't have an error or something like that.

Comment: Here is an informative and easy to understand discussion on Type I, II and even III tests. [Unbalanced Factorial Designs](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/unbalanced.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`anova` is a function in base R.  `Anova` is a function in the `car` package.

The former calculates type I tests, that is, each variable is added in sequential order.  The latter calculates type II or III tests. Type II tests test each variable after all the others. For details, see ?Anova.