# car::Anova with random factor or lmer with random factor

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have 36 rats, some are highly impulsive (HI), some are low-impulsive (LI) and some are MIDs. I ran them on two separate days on an attention task with a variable ITI paradigm whereby a cue is presented pseudo-randomly after 3s, 5s, 7s and 9s. I'm looking at the probability of making a correct response (DV) as a function of the impulsivity phenotype (3 levels); Day (2 levels) and the ITI (4 levels), my random effect is rat_ID.

I'm not sure whether I should use lmer or car::Anova with a random factor, below are codes for both:

```
model = lme(prob_correct ~ Day*ITI*impulsivity, random=~1|rat_ID,
             data=mydat2,
            method="REML")

Anova(model)
```

OR

```
lmecoeff<- lmer(prob_correct~Day*ITI*impulsivity+(1|rat_ID), data= mydat2)
anova(lmecoeff)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences between `car::Anova` and `base::anova` are discussed in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144838/42952). The answer is the same for linear mixed models. These functions calculate different types tests: `anova` calculates type I tests, while `Anova` calculates type II or type III tests. The differences between these tests are a little tricky to understand, but [this blog post](http://md.psych.bio.uni-goettingen.de/mv/unit/lm_cat/lm_cat_unbal_ss_explained.html) is a good starting place.

Your `lme()` and `lmer()` models should be the same in this case.
You can confirm this by comparing `anova(model)` to `anova(lmecoeff)`, or `car::Anova(model)` to `car::Anova(lmecoeff)`.

Comment: Ok thank you! There's probably a plethora of posts on this, but I'm having a hard time deciding whether to use lmer or aov() with an error term..any post that you can easily think about? can I use emmeans() with aov()?